# Using xScale to mirrored square node become rectangle

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, sprite, scale

I wanted to square image after hit wall turn opposite direction using `xScale = -1` but after collision square turns, but it become a rectangle. Here are code I use:
**For square**

```
ball = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed @"ball .png"];
ball .physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithCircleOfRadius:ball.size.width/2];
ball .position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2.self.frame/size.height/2);
[self addchild:ball];
```

And at `didBeginContact` I use `ball.xScale = -1.0` and `ball.xScale = 1.0` What I do wrong, and what do I need to change to avoid it?
**Edit** I read that somebody have similar problem, and solution on that was this:

```
ball.xScale = -1.0
ball.physicsBody = ball.physicsBody;
```

But it didn't work for me, so what can be the problem?

**Edit 2** well, i guess my ball image was big and after `ball.xScale = -1.0` ball in x scale decreased, after I change `ball.xScale = -1.5` it changes and didn't change any size.

Comment: His physicBody become a rectangle or his image?

Comment: only image, I use `showsPhysics` and I see that physics are the same, but only image is that who changing

Comment: It's strange. Try to have 2 images (normal and mirror) and change it at the contact, works?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia well yeah, that works, but  is there another way only with one image?

Comment: I think is better to use 2 images, Apple applied this method on the example DemoBots

Comment: @SimonePistecchia thank you, I will keep it mind, next time I will use your suggestion, but for this I will leave code like this.

Comment: Did you check if the size and the  xScale is correct after init the ball?